# How do you collaborate on Flash Builder projects?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-builder

Flash builder project files can't be opened on another computer even if the files were copied, for e.g. through version control like git or svn.

Importing and Exporting fxp projects is not possible as we do not want to overwrite files for git or svn unnecessarily.

How do people collaborate on Flash Builder projects without creating new project in Flash Builder and having to set up all the settings for the project again and again for multiple collaborators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved in Flash Builder 4.7 where you can actually import the project folder as is.

Answer (score 3):

If you import the project using its folder location as per @Sean Fujiwara answer then:

One useful way to collaborate in Flash Builder projects is to utilise environment variables. You can access these using - `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Linked Resources`:

[image]

From here you can add a new variable or edit an existing one, from the example above you can see that we use a `FRAMEWORK_SOURCE` variable which points to the source for our shared framework code, we use a swc but this is handy for debugging errors.

We also have another variable called `OUTPUT_FOLDER` which in our case points to a folder where we run our project over localhost see example below, to use this in a project, you go to `right click project name > Properties > ActionScript Build Path`, here you enter the folder name you want creating inside the folder that `OUTPUT_FOLDER` points to:

[image]

When you do a `Project > Clean` from the menu, all resources from your `html-template` folder will be copied across to this folder and it should open in a browser.

Now we have been able to check in to SVN our `.project` and `.actionScriptProperities` files with few issues. When someone new to the project checks them out, they will get an Error in the Problems panel telling them they don't have for example - `OUTPUT_FOLDER\MyProjectName`, therefore the project leader should have a document listing all the required variables to be setup in your environment.

Other things you can share are paths to raw font files etc.

The only problem I've had with this approach is sometimes it asks for the path to the SDK if it is different from your location, not had chance to figure this one out yet.

Comment: Thanks Neil, getting the local workspace specific settings out of the project file, and into the local workspace settings, has just made us a much happier group of developers!

Answer (score 0):

> Flash builder project files can't be opened on another computer even
>   if the files were copied, for e.g. through version control like git or
>   svn.

Flash builder projects can be imported into the workspace just like other Eclipse projects.

Once you copy them to another computer:

1. Right click in package explorer and go to `Import...`.
2. Select `General/Existing Projects into Workspace`.
3. Select the folder containing the `.project` directory.

If you make sure `Copy projects into workspaces` is deselected, you can commit the files directly from wherever you checked the code out.